# How do I replace the cartridge on this tap?

Tags: taps, cartridge

I have this specific tap
https://www.screwfix.com/p/seaford-basin-mono-mixer-tap-with-pop-up-waste/853fv
On my bathroom basin. It is leaking from the cold water stem when turned on, so I believe I need to replace the cartridge on that side.

I have consulted several articles and videos and it's fairly clear what has to happen, but I cannot figure out how to remove the handle.

I have several theories, but nothing wants to budge (probably in part because of 10 years of hard water) and I don't want to apply the level of force required to turn a jammed 10 year old part unless I know I'm doing it the right way.

So does anyone know specifically how to gain access to the cartridge on the above linked tap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately that seems to be a discount "unbranded" faucet; in other words it is likely mass produced in the far east or is an unlabeled version from a more common manufacturer. As such, finding parts diagrams to help with disassembly will probably be just as difficult as finding any actual parts.

I will say that the cartridge for this style is commonly accessed by removing the chrome "button" at the top of the handle, then removing a screw underneath that holds the handle on. Once the handle is unfastened and removed (which may require a *handle puller* tool if it's stuck), then the threaded chrome collar is unscrewed anti-clockwise (when looking from the top). Then the cartridge can be pulled directly out.

Comment: I suspected something like that might be the case, thanks for your input you have basically confirmed what I had already scraped together. Any suggestions as to how the caps are most likely to come off? My current two best guesses are that either the caps come off as you suggested or one or more of the arms unscrew to reveal a grub screw underneath.

Comment: If there were no cap (but it looks like there is...) I would say a screw-off arm might *be* the set screw. It looks like small chrome caps on top that simply pry off to reveal a hold-down screw. Good luck.

Comment: I finally got this thing apart, the arms do unscrew but it's not clear why as it achieves nothing. As you suggested the cap on the top comes off, it unscrews. I eventually resorted to mole grips to get purchase on it. Once the head is off, the cover unscrews and then the cartridge can be unscrewed with a spanner.